# How can I align minipages by their absolute top, rather than their uppermost baseline?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have two `minipage`s side-by-side, and one is of a larger font size than the other – this is to produce a title. However, the baselines of the minipages are aligned, and not the top. I would prefer for the text in both minipages to align at their tops rather than their baselines.

Here is a minimal working example, and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Show the frame to see the line I would like to align at.
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{80pt}\huge Baseline\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Baseline baseline with lots and lots of text, consider this a paragraph\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Produced Output]

To be clear, I would like for the paragraph on the right to touch the top line just like the `\huge` text on the left.

I tried to align the top by first having a `\rule{0pt}{1em}\vspace{-1em}` before the paragraphs start, but this doesn't work, presumably due to the change in line separation in different sizes, and the alignment gets even worse. I won't show the result but here's the code for that anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
% This does NOT produce the desired result.
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{80pt}%
    \rule{0pt}{1em}\vspace{-1em}

    \huge Baseline
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}%
    \rule{0pt}{1em}\vspace{-1em}

    Baseline baseline with lots and lots of text, consider this a paragraph
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

So: how can I align the tops of these minipages, rather than aligning their top baseline?

Comment: You can add a `\vspace{0pt}` in the beginning of each one.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This aligns them, but adds extra space at the top - how can I remove this extra space? Presumably it is another `\baselineskip`, right? EDIT: it's `1em` and this solves the issue.

Comment: Hm... There's that... Sorry, I don't know. I'll retract my close vote. It _looks like_ that if you set `\topskip=0pt` before the `minipages` (and make sure you restore it after) that extra space will disappear. I'm not sure if this is correct, though.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by @Phelype Oleninik, adding a `\vspace{0pt}` aligns the two with an extra line which is `\topskip` tall. Hence adding the line `\vspace{0pt}\vspace{-\topskip}`, or even just `\vspace{-\topskip}`, aligns the two paragraphs at the top of their `minipages`. Here is working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{80pt}%
    \vspace{-\topskip}
    \huge Baseline
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}%
    \vspace{-\topskip}
    Baseline baseline with lots and lots of text, consider this a paragraph
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Coincidentally (more or less) `1em` is `10.00002pt`, and the `\topskip` is `10pt` by default... Perhaps `\vspace{-\topskip}` :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik A good point, `\topskip` it is! Using `\topskip` also produces better results with higher point-sizes.

Answer (score 3):

The `\belowbaseline[<depth>]{<content>}` macro of `stackengine`. Note, there is a corresponding `\abovebaseline[<height>]{<content>}` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
% Show the frame to see the line I would like to align at.
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\begin{minipage}[t]{80pt}\huge Baseline\end{minipage}}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Baseline baseline with lots and 
  lots of text, consider this a paragraph\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to also work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Show the frame to see the line I would like to align at.
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{minipage}[t]{80pt}\huge Baseline\end{minipage}}
                         \raisebox{-\height}{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Baseline baseline with lots and lots of text, consider this a paragraph\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One can use `\raisebox` to move the baseline of a box (with TeX everything is a box).  It should be noted that the first baseline of a page is located `\topskip` below the actual top.  Otherwise, one should use `\ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Show the frame to see the line I would like to align at.
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\noindent
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{\begin{minipage}[t]{80pt}\huge Baseline\end{minipage}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Baseline baseline with lots and lots of text, consider this a paragraph\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]